# How to create login on external site to angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drupal

I am needing to create a login form on an informational drupal CMS that when submitted loads and logs into my angular JS application. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi.. Im having a similar requirement now.. Have you achieved what you were looking for ?

Comment: Implementing a saml or oauth login handshake is the correct way to do it. We decided against creating SSO in our case though.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a route 
/login/:username/:password
in your Angular app which handles the login with the given credentials.

This route needs to be called/invoked (simply by href-referencing) by your external CMS with the needed parameters (username, password) after submitting the form.

For security reasons it is of course recommended to use something more "intelligent" like a hashed password, or a token (idealy given by a server) instead of a plaintext password, of course